# Why should we give the number of pages on arXiv?

Tags: arxiv

In https://arxiv.org/help/prep I found

> Indicate number of pages and number of figures. If desired, include Tex flavor or related comments. Do not bother to put "uuencoded" or "gzipped tar file" even if you submitted it this way.

I wonder why this is considered to be helpful. And what are pages anyway? The number of PDF pages? The number of "content" pages (= PDF pages - title page (if any) - blank pages - reference pages - appendix)?

Comment: I think this is just because people casually browsing the arXIv like to know roughly how long the paper is before they click the link. (Maybe they are interested enough to read a 15-page paper but not a 50-page one.)

Comment: To provide basic error checking.

Comment: I agree the number of pages is important and useful, for the reason explained by Anonymous above. However, "number of figures" has always baffled and bemused me. Certain math textbook series still have the habit of touting the number of figures on the inside cover page as if that's one of the most important things about the book. Why not highlight the "number of theorems" instead? I'm guessing this is a relic from long gone days in which producing a graphic figure for a textbook took hard work and was considered an impressive achievement, so publishers mentioned this to impress the readers.

Comment: @DanRomik Having written a [book about Geometry and Topology](https://github.com/MartinThoma/LaTeX-examples/raw/master/documents/GeoTopo/GeoTopo.pdf) I would still say making figures is much work. I think it might give you an impression of the book. So a book with 100 pages but only 10 graphics might give a different impression than 70 pages and 30 graphics. Depending on what you look for, that might be good or bad.

Comment: However, I don't think all of this should really matter when it comes to usual internet speeds (for Germany at least) and usual sizes of arxiv papers. Then I'm faster just downloading the PDF and having a look myself than looking at those numbers and thinking about what this means for me.

Comment: @moose having written [a book about longest increasing subsequences](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~romik/book/), I would totally agree with you. :-) However, as much as figures take a lot of work to create, I still don't think the number of figures is an especially important parameter of a book (for 98% of books at least), and certainly not _the_ most important parameter after the number of pages. For most books this is a nearly information-less statistic and communicating it in such a prominent way is a waste of cognitive capacity.

Comment: @DanRomik I remember seeing a Springer GTM as an undergrad (now I forget which) that say "with 1 figure."  Naturally I tried to find this figure as it must be so important to merit singular mention, but I sadly could not.  When the 2nd ed came out, it omitted any mention of figures.

Comment: @MartinThoma: I can imagine that the number of pages could matter at places with slow internet connections, so such concerns are entirely out of place, event today.

Comment: @Ambicion When you have a slow connection, the file size matters, not the number of pages. The file size can be determined automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Page length is one of the most basic things you can know about a document, and one of the few useful numerical measurements of a piece of writing.  I personally find it helpful as an indicator of how "serious" something is.  (This holds for novels as well as papers.)  If I see one set of notes on a topic that are 8 pages long versus another set that are 56 pages, I have a good sense that the latter set is much more detailed than the former.  Similarly, a 6-page paper entitled "Bounded gaps between primes" (a famously hard problem, very unlikely to be solved in so short a work) gives a very different impression than [a 54-page paper with the same title](http://annals.math.princeton.edu/2014/179-3/p07).

While page length is not equated with how deep or interesting something is (and of course depends on format), it can be at least suggestive.  As a corollary, I also take page lengths into account when evaluating job candidates to get a sense of how productive they are.

Regarding the definition, I think it's safe to interpret page length as the number of pdf pages, as this is what most people will immediately see when they open the pdf.  That said, if it's a book, it's perfectly fine to put something like 286+xvii pages, but I doubt people will care much either way.  Remember, this is just a preprint server.

Comment: With "format" I guess you mean `IEEEtran` vs `article` which makes about 2.5x the difference? Or do you mean `A5` vs `A4` (vs the american ones) which makes again a big difference?

Comment: @moose Format includes all of those differences and others, and no reasonable formatting choice will turn a 6-page paper into a 60-page one.  (BTW, I'm in pure math and we almost never use IEEEtran-like formats, and I've never seen anyone use A5.  It's rare that I see more than a 50% difference in length because of format choice, and I don't think I've ever seen more than 2x.)

Comment: I recently worked in pattern recognition and computer vision. There, IEEEtran (or at least two column designs) seem to be used quite often. On one of my documents, I tried it. When I switched from IEEEtran to article, without changing anything else, I got from 4 pages to 10 pages (no empty pages or something similar).